# How to add some parameters in event handles on echarts?

Tags: echarts

I need to send specific data on backend after click on the line in ECharts.
My codesandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/stacked-line-chart-forked-u1qxvc?file=/index.js

After clicking on the line we get parameters as arguments of callback.
If we console.log(parameters), then in console we can see this stuff:

```
componentType: "series"
componentSubType: "line"
componentIndex: 4
seriesIndex: 4
seriesName: "Search Engine"
seriesType: "line"
event: Object
type: "click"
```

Can I somehow add some data in this info?

Like:

```
componentType: "series"
componentSubType: "line"
componentIndex: 4
seriesIndex: 4
seriesName: "Search Engine"
seriesType: "line"
event: Object
type: "click"
newData: [1, 2, 3]
```

Then I can get this newData from parameters and send it to backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additional data could be stored in [datasets](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#dataset) and later retrieved on click.
Also take a look at [other attributes](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-line.label.formatter) to be retrieved in params.
Example - a column 'more' with additional data.

```
option = {
  dataset: {
    source: [
      ['score', 'amount', 'product', 'more'],
      [89.3, 58212, 'Matcha Latte','A'],
      [57.1, 78254, 'Milk Tea','B'],
      [74.4, 41032, 'Cheese Cocoa','C'],
      [50.1, 12755, 'Cheese Brownie','D'],
      [89.7, 20145, 'Matcha Cocoa','E'],
      [68.1, 79146, 'Tea','F'],
    ]
  },
  grid: { containLabel: true },
  xAxis: { },
  yAxis: { type: 'category' },
  series: [
    {
      type: 'bar',
      encode: {
        x: 'amount',
        y: 'product'
      }
    }
  ]
};
myChart.on("click", (params) => { // "series.bar",
  console.log(params.data[3]); // retrieve 'more' column content
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I wish I could do it without dataset, but I guess it's the only way to add some data in series